# Как лучше реализовать список с большим количеством компонентов?

Tags: android, design

У меня в приложении на `Activity` информация представлена в следующим образом
**Заголовок 1**
*текст а*
*текст б*
*текст в*
**Заголовок 2**
*текст г*
*текст д*
**Заголовок 3**
и так далее

причем подзаголовки должны быть скрыты и при нажатии на заголовки должны выезжать.
Как мне лучше это реализовать? Я делал сначала просто `LinearLayout`, в котором находились `TextView`, и с помощью `setVisibility` делал нужные мне `Layout` видимыми, но студия выдала предупреждение:
`activity_main.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance`
Я решил поэкспериментировать и сделать это через `RecyclerView`. Создал класс:

```
public class MyLayout {

    LinearLayout llMain;
    String markа

    MyLayout (LinearLayout llMain, String mark) {
        this.llMain = llMain;
        this.mark = mark;
    }
}
```

Этот класс добавлял в `List` и передавал в `Adapter`. В качестве параметра `mark` передавал текст с указанием заголовок 1 или заголовок 2 или `Layout` с текстом. llMain - это `Layout`, который я передаю и в котором находится мой текст (в зависимости от mark этот `Layout` различается). Вот код адаптера:

```
class RVAdapterForFullConfig extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterForFullConfig.LinearViewHolder> {

class LinearViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cvMain;

    PopupDetail popupDetail;

    LinearViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cvMain = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvMain);

        popupDetail = new PopupDetail();
        cvMain.setOnClickListener(popupDetail);
    }
}

private List<MyLayout> linearLayouts;

RVAdapterForFullConfig(List<MyLayout> linearLayouts) {
    this.linearLayouts = linearLayouts;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public RVAdapterForFullConfig.LinearViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_for_activity_filter, parent, false);
    return new LinearViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RVAdapterForFullConfig.LinearViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyLayout myLayout = linearLayouts.get(position);
    holder.cvMain.addView(myLayout.llMain);

    holder.popupDetail.setMyLayout(myLayout);
    holder.popupDetail.setContext(holder.itemView.getContext());
    holder.popupDetail.setCvMain(holder.cvMain);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return linearLayouts.size();
}

private void popup(MyLayout myLayout, Context context, CardView cvMain) {
    int position = linearLayouts.indexOf(myLayout);

    MyLayout myLayout2 = linearLayouts.get(position + 1);

    if (myLayout.mark.equals("proc")) {
        createDetailProc(position, context);
    } else if (myLayout.mark.equals("cooling") && !myLayout2.mark.equals("detail")) {
        createDetailCooling(position, context);
    } else if (myLayout.mark.equals("mboard") && !myLayout2.mark.equals("detail")) {
        createDetailCooling(position, context);
    } else if (myLayout.mark.equals("detail")) {
        delete(myLayout, cvMain);
    }
}
private void createDetailProc(int position, Context context) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setLayoutParams(params);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("Здесь будут характеристики процессора");
    tv.setTextSize(25);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);

    ll.addView(tv);

    linearLayouts.add(position + 1, new MyLayout(ll, "detail"));
    notifyItemInserted(position + 1);
}
private void createDetailCooling(int position, Context context) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setLayoutParams(params);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("Здесь будут характеристики куллера");
    tv.setTextSize(25);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);

    ll.addView(tv);

    linearLayouts.add(position + 1, new MyLayout(ll, "detail"));
    notifyItemInserted(position + 1);
}

private void delete(MyLayout myLayout, CardView cvMain) {
    cvMain.removeAllViews();
    int position = linearLayouts.indexOf(myLayout);
    linearLayouts.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

private class PopupDetail implements View.OnClickListener {

    MyLayout myLayout;
    Context context;
    CardView cvMain;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popup(myLayout, context, cvMain);
    }

    void setMyLayout(MyLayout myLayout) {
        this.myLayout = myLayout;
    }
    void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    void setCvMain(CardView cvMain) {
        this.cvMain = cvMain;
    }
}
}
```

Layou файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cvMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/color_background_activity">


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Проблема в том, что приходится очищать `CardView` в ручную, так как иначе его состояние и дочерние элементы запоминаются и накладываются друг на друга. А если, например, видно текст под одним их заголовков:
**Заголовок 1**
*текст а*
*текст б*
*текст в*
**Заголовок 2**
**Заголовок 3**
и я захочу этот текст скрыть нажав на заголовок, а не на сам текст, то смогу получить только `CardView` заголовка, а у текста как получить я не знаю.
Вроде все свои методы расписал, вопрос в том, как лучше мне это реализовать? каким то другим способом или же одним из вышеописанных, если мой метод с `Recyclerview`, то как мне решить проблему с очисткой `CardView`?
Вот, что у меня получилось, когда я использовал `LinearLayout` и создавал разметку вручную
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пытаетесь изобрести `ExpandableListView` ?

Comment: @pavlofff Я пробовал сделать с помощью `ExpandableListView `, но посчитал, что это немного не то, что мне нужно